# How to replace every single HTML section in a large file in Python?

Tags: python

I have several hundreds of long files with repeated blocks of HTML in each that I won't need for my further text analysis, therefore I would like to get rid of them as they occupy quite a lot of valuable memory when analyzing these files.

These HTML blocks are occasionally broken by a newline character. Just like regular HTML, the removable blocks always begin with `<!DOCTYPE` and end with `</html>`.

My approach was the following:

```
content = inputfile.read()
pattern = re.compile('<!DOCTYPE.*[\s\S]*<\/html>')
match = pattern.findall(content)
```

However, this always returns only one single match. The regex correctly identifies the very first instance of `<!DOCTYPE` and the very last instance of `</html>`. Thus, even if I have 10,000 HTML blocks across the document that I want to remove using

```
content = re.sub(pattern, '', content)
```

only one match has been found and thus, almost my whole file gets removed.

How could I find all the HTML blocks separately throughout the document?

P.S.: I use Python3.x and my OS is Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are greedy by default. That means it searches until it finds the last `<\HTML>` instance. Change your expression as follows:

```
pattern = re.compile('<!DOCTYPE.*?<\/html>', flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: The problem is the frequent appearance of newline characters separating parts of the HTML code. This is why I used ```[\s\S]*``` in my original code. Using ```.*?``` won't find these newline characters.

Comment: Oh, I've just seen you updated it with the ```flags``` parameter!

Comment: I realized that and already changed my answer with the `re.DOTALL` flag.

Comment: You may need the `re.IGNORECASE` flag as well... depends on you input text.

Comment: Good to hear ;-) If you want to specify the re.IGNORE case flag do it as follows: `pattern = re.compile('<!DOCTYPE.*?<\/html>', flags=re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)` (with a vertical bar)